# How can I generate a polynomial?

Tags: complex, polynomials

Suppose, z1 = 0.1 + 0.5i and z2 = 0.1 - 0.5i are from in a unit circle.

How can I find a polynomial of the form $z^2 - az -b$ from (z - z1)*(z - z2)

I tried,

```
z1 = 0.1 + 0.5i;
z2 = 0.1 - 0.5i ;

Expand[(z-z1)(z-z2)]
```

It gave the folowing output in Mathematica7

$0.01+0. i-0.25 i^2-0.2 z+0. i z+z^2$

And,

$-0.25 i^2+z^2-0.2 z+0.01$

in Mathematica-11.

Comment: There's no such thing as `i`. For an imaginary unit, type `I` - capitalization matters. Use also `Chop`.

Comment: You need to use a capital `I` to represent the complex part of your `z1` and `z2`. This will help.

Comment: @user6014 Imaginary part; the whole number is complex. In fact, a real number is also complex - it just has its imaginary part equal to zero.

Comment: Ah, I was sloppy with it. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

Consider (with the capital `I`'s):

```
z1 = 0.1 + 0.5 I;
z2 = 0.1 - 0.5 I;
Chop@Expand[(z - z1) (z - z2)]
```

which will give you

```
0.26 - 0.2 z + z^2
```

where your $a =$ `-0.2` and $b =$ `0.26`.